# Excel VBA IE Object and using dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, css-selectors, webdriver

I am experimenting with web automation and struggling a bit trying to utilize a drop down list.

My code works up to the point of searching for a company name and hitting "go". On the new page I can't seem to find the right code that selects the group of elements that represents the drop down list. I then want to select "100" entries, but I can't even grab the nodes that represent this list.

I have been browsing multiple different pages on stackoverflow that talk about CSS selectors and looked at tutorials but that doesn't seem to help either. I either end up grabbing nothing, or whatever I grab can't use the `getElementsByTagName` method, which ultimately I am trying to drill down into the `td` and `select` nodes . Not sure what to do with those yet, but I can't even grab them. Thoughts?

(note stopline is just a line that I use a breakpoint on to stop my code)

CSS helper website: `https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp`

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim stopLine As Integer
    
    Dim oSearch As Object, oSearchButton As Object
    
    Dim oForm As Object
    Dim oSelect As Object
    Dim list As Object
    
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html"
    
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    
    Set doc = ie.Document
    
    Set oSearch = doc.getElementById("companysearchform")
    Set oSearchButton = oSearch.getElementsByTagName("input")(1)
    Set oSearch = oSearch.getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
    oSearch.Value = "Summit Midstream Partners, LP"
    
    oSearchButton.Click
    
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    
    Set doc = ie.Document
    
    Set list = doc.querySelectorAll("td select")
    
    
    stopLine = 1
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrHandle:
        MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
        Exit Sub
        
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Set list = doc.querySelector("#count") seems to return nothing when i look at the locals window in excel.

Comment: Did you leave a long enough wait? Execute line by line with F8

Comment: isn't that what the second set of "do events" loop is for? After i click search it waits for the next webpage to be ready correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`td select` will return a single node so you only need `querySelector`. The node has an id so you might as well use the quicker `querySelector("#count")` to target the parent `select`. To change the option you can then use `SelectedIndex` on the parent select, or, target the child option by its `value` attribute `querySelector("[value='100']").Selected = True`. You may then need to attach and trigger `change/onchange` htmlevent to the parent `select` to register the change.

However, I would simply extract the company CIK from current page then concatenate the count=100 param into the url and `.Navigate2` that using following format:

```
https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001549922&type=&dateb=&owner=include&count=100&search_text=
```

You can extract CIK, after initial search company click and wait for page load, with:

```
Dim cik As String

cik = ie.document.querySelector("[name=CIK]").value

ie.Navigate2 "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=" & cik & "&type=&dateb=&owner=include&count=100&search_text="
```

Given several params are left blank you can likely shorten to:

```
"https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=" & cik & "&owner=include&count=100"
```

---

If you are unable to get the initial parent select you probably need a timed loop waiting for that element to be present after clicking the search button. An example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51166610/6241235) in a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: timer seemed to fix it - thanks!. just out of curiosity, what is the difference between the doevents and the timer? Theoretically i would assume they are  almost redundant functions, with the doevents being more robust because it is actually waiting on a status from the ie object rather than just waiting an arbitrary amount of time for the object to not equal nothing.

Comment: The timer is concerned with looping until your specified exit conditions are met.   [DoEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function)- _Yields execution so that the operating system can process other events._ You should have both page load wait conditions of Whilst ie.Busy Or Ie.ReadyState <> 4. For dynamic pages this does not guarantee all content has loaded.